# Need to populate Long text field with email addresses from different object's records

Tags: apex

I have a "Job" Custom Object with a long text field on it.  I'd like to fill that long text field with email addresses from Accounts that contain the same "Opportunities" and "Pipelines".

So if a Job's Opportunity or Pipeline fields (both multiselect picklist) contain the same values as an Account's Opportunity or Pipeline fields, then the email address from the Account should populate the long text email address field on the Job object.

So my goal in the end is to have multiple email addresses in the long text field.

I have built a few triggers before, but am not really sure where to even begin with this one since the records aren't related.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can't this be done with a workflow?

Comment: What event do you expect to fire the trigger on? After Insert or After-Update of Opportunity? It then will do what? Either collect the data itself or collect the necessary ID's needed to Query for the data, so you can insert the data into your Custom field on your "Job" Custom Object? Does that help get you started? Now lets see your first stab at some code. ;)

Comment: Thanks crmprogdev, here's my code so far:

`trigger JobsEmail on AVTRRT__Job__c (before insert, before update) {
    for (AVTRRT__Job__c myJob : Trigger.new) {
    if (myJob.Send_CCP__c != NULL) {
        List<Account> toemail = [SELECT Id, Account_Manager_eMail_1__c FROM Account
                                    WHERE Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c INCLUDES (**AVTRRT__Job__c.Account**)];
                                   }
                                  }
}
`
The ** area doesn't work at the moment, and I also need a way to string all the emails together.  Suggestions?